# What exactly is WebTransport Protocol?.How is it different from Websocket?

Tags: websocket, protocols, webtransport

I have written applications in WebSockets protocol before. Now that i came to know  about  a new technology called WebTransport protocol.How is it different from WebSocket protocol and will it replace Websockets in the future?